# Half time duration

Tags: rules, football, officiating

I have read through the FIFA laws of the game and can see that the half time interval says:

Half-time interval
Players are entitled to an interval at half-time.
The half-time interval must not exceed 15 minutes.
Competition rules must state the duration of the half-time interval.
The duration of the half-time interval may be altered only with the consent of
the referee.

We play amateur U18 football in the UK, with 45 minutes per half. I have looked through our leagues handbook and can find no mention of the duration.

Is it reasonable for the referee to insist on only 5 minutes half time interval?

The above rule was taken from the [FA laws of the game.](http://www.thefa.com/football-rules-governance/laws/football-11-11/law-7---the-duration-of-the-match)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but for normal the ref asks both teams if they're ok with it.

On the otherside, if it's realy cold weather mostly the teams asking the ref for a shorter halftime interval.

(If the ref blows the whistle after only 5min halftime interval, it's easy to max it for another 5min.)

Answer (score -3):

Not more than fifteen minutes but not less than five minutes

Comment: Do you have a reference for this information?